# JavaScript copy value optgroup to other input

Tags: javascript, html-select, optgroup

I have selected option:

```
<form>
<select name="sel" id="sel" onchange="run()">
<option selected disabled>Wybierz...</option>
  <optgroup id="user" value="user" label="user">
    <option value="1">michal</option>
    <option value="2">mateusz</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup id="warehouse" value="warehouse" label="warehouse">
    <option value="1">kosz</option>
    <option value="2">zaginione</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</form>


<input type="text" name="copy" id="copy"></input>
```

And script to add text in input text:

```
function run() {
    if(document.getElementById("user").label == 'user'){

      document.getElementById("copy").value = "user";

    } else if (document.getElementById("warehouse").label == 'warehouse') {

        document.getElementById("copy").value = "warehouse";

    }
}
```

When user selected option with first `optgroup`("user") then in input text script add name "user". When user selected records from second `optgroup`, then script change text in input text to "warehouse". But in my script, nothing is added to the input text.
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7yv12vm0/1/)

Comment: you have use onload option for js .https://jsfiddle.net/7yv12vm0/2/  but your comparison is incorrect `document.getElementById("user").label` is always user

Comment: Do you want the input's value to be **`michal`** or **`mateusz`** or just say **`user`**? That part is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/7yv12vm0/3/)

in jsfiddle you have put function inside onload function so it is undifined to outer scope.outherwise you will get `user` for both groups
`document.getElementById("user").label == 'user'` is always true.so it is not going to else block.you should get label value of selected group and compare it.

```
var lable=event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].parentNode.label // get lable value of clicked group
if(lable == 'user'){

  document.getElementById("copy").value = "user";

} else if (lable == 'warehouse') {

    document.getElementById("copy").value = "warehouse";

}
```